# Let $P, Q, R$ be finite posets. Prove that $P^{Q+R} \cong P^Q \times P^R$.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Can someone please verify my proof and offer suggestions for improvement? I feel that my proof might have been a little hand-waving in showing that $\varphi$ is a bijection, and I feel that it is not too readable.

Some preliminaries: If $Q$ and $R$ are posets, $Q+R$ is the poset on $Q \cup R$. Similarly, if $A$ and $B$ are posets, $(x, y) \leq_{A \times B}  (x', y') \iff x \leq_A x'$ and $y \leq_B y'$. If $P$ and $Q$ are posets, $P^Q$ is the poset consisting of all order preserving functions from $Q$ to $P$, where $f \leq g \iff f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in P$.

> Let $P, Q, R$ be finite posets. Prove that $P^{Q+R} \cong P^Q \times P^R$.

Let $\varphi:P^{Q+R} \longrightarrow P^Q \times P^R$ be defined by $\varphi(f) = (f|_Q, f|_R)$. $\varphi$ is clearly a bijection. It remains to show that $\varphi$ is order preserving. Clearly, if $f, g \in P^{Q+R}$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
f \leq g &\iff& f(x) \leq g(x) \ \ (\forall x \in Q+R) \\
&\iff& f|_Q(x) \leq g|_Q(x),\ f|_R(y) \leq g|_R(y) \ \ (\forall x \in Q, y \in R) \\
&\iff& f|_Q \leq g|_Q, f|_R \leq g|_R \\
&\iff& \varphi(f) \leq \varphi(g)
\end{eqnarray}

This completes the proof.

Comment: This seems good enough for me. Note that you didn't use finiteness nor that $P$ and $Q$ are posets.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Where does the proof break down if we do not assume finiteness?

Comment: How do you define $Q+R$? What order are you using on $P^Q \times P^R$? Is it the lexicographic order?

Comment: @GitGud If $Q$ and $R$ are posets, $Q+R$ is the poset on $Q \cup R$. Similarly, if $A$ and $B$ are posets, $(x, y) \leq_{A \times B}  (x', y') \iff x \leq_A x'$ and $y \leq_B y'$.

Comment: I take it the order $\leq$ on $Q\cup R$ for $x\in Q$ and $y\in R$ is $x\leq y$ by definition.

Comment: @GitGud No. Elements of $Q$ are incomparable to those of $R$.

Comment: @user154185 I'm not sure that's standard. What happens when $Q\cap R\neq \varnothing$?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry. To be more precise, $x \leq_{P + Q} y$ if and only if one of the conditions ($x, y \in P$ and $x \leq_P y$) and ($x, y \in Q$ and $x \leq_Q y$) holds.

Comment: I think it's fine. Finiteness doesn't seem necessary to me.